# Create symlink for a folder, not a file

Tags: unix, symlink

I have two different folders, say folder 1 and folder 2. A bunch of files get created into folder 1 all the time (they're not there yet).

I would like to have those files "physically" in folder 2, but that they are "symbolically" in folder 1 (because for new files to still get created in folder 1, it needs to have the previous files in it too).

I know I can create a `symlink` for a particular file from one folder to another.

But how would it work to have in general ALL future files from folder 1 (with different names) be physically in folder 2 and symbolically in folder 1?

I guess I would have to have a line that moves them physically to folder 2, AND that creates a symlink to folder 1.

I tried:

```
ln -s ./output/* ../../data/jadecheclair/plasim_output/fix_alb/output_try/*
```

where `./output/` is the folder they get created in (folder 1) and `../../data/jadecheclair/plasim_output/fix_alb/output_try/` is the folder I would like them to be in physically.

Comment: Why you don't create a symlink between two folders, like ln -s folder_1 folder_2 ?

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is move all old files the nes directory, remove it and create your link:

```
mv ./output/* ../../data/jadecheclair/plasim_output/fix_alb/output_try/
rm -ri ./output/
ln -s ../../data/jadecheclair/plasim_output/fix_alb/output_try/ ./output/
```

Then you should have

```
$ ls -la
[..]
output -> ../../data/jadecheclair/plasim_output/fix_alb/output_try/
```

And files created in `./output/` should be physically in `..../output_try/`

Comment: Thus would give me the error that the directory ./output doesn't exist (if I deleted it prior to this).
If I create it before writing this line, it still writes the files into ./output :/

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. Have you tried it? I don't understand what *Thus would* means.

Comment: *This would*, sorry.
I think the issue is that I need a direct line in my shell script to save the files into the source folder instead of into the linked folder. It looks like there is no way to do this via symlink. However, what you wrote works once those files get created into the source folder.